# How to parse multipe json value in java

Tags: java, json, parsing, stringbuilder

I've below json value in my StringBuilder variable, I want to parse all **id** key value and store it again in StringBuilder.

```
{"status":"success","id":"1"}
{"status":"success","id":"2"}
{"status":"success","id":"3"}
{"status":"success","id":"4"}
{"status":"success","id":"5"}
{"status":"success","id":"6"}
```

Expected output:
1
2
3
4
5
6

How can I parse these value in java?

I tried below option but it doesn't help:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.append(jsonStringValue);

JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(str);
jObj.getString("id");
```

**Using JSONTokener**

```
JSONTokener t = new JSONTokener(str.toString());
 while (t.more()) {
JSONObject o2 = (JSONObject) t.nextValue();
System.out.println(o2.getString("id"));
}
```

But I'm getting below error message:
org.json.JSONException: Missing value at character 128

Comment: that is not valid JSON, each line is valid, but the entire thing is not

Comment: Exact Duplicate; One of Many: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using org.json, You can use JSONTokener.

Here's example shows how it works.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws JSONException {
    String str1 = "{\"strValue\":\"string\"}\n{\"intValue\":1}";
    JSONTokener t = new JSONTokener(str1);
    JSONObject o1 = (JSONObject) t.nextValue();
    JSONObject o2 = (JSONObject) t.nextValue();
    System.out.println(o1.getString("strValue"));
    System.out.println(o2.getLong("intValue"));
    System.out.println(t.more()); // Check if there's more token. can be used to process with loop.
}
```

Or if you can change input string, you can put those object into Json array.

```
[
{"status":"success","id":"1"},
{"status":"success","id":"2"},
{"status":"success","id":"3"},
{"status":"success","id":"4"},
{"status":"success","id":"5"},
{"status":"success","id":"6"}
]
```

In that case you can use org.json.JSONArray to handle it.

Comment: Hi, I tried you approach but I'm getting this exception org.json.JSONException: Missing value at character 128 . I've updated my code in original post.. can you correct me if i'm doing something wrong

Comment: Did you escape double quotation?
Should be like
    builder.append("{\"status\":\"success\",\"id\":\"1\"}");

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexps like this

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder inputBuf = prepareStringBuilder();

    StringBuilder outputBuf = new StringBuilder();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":\"(\\d+)\"");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputBuf);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String group = matcher.group(1);
        outputBuf.append(group);
    }

    System.out.println(outputBuf);
}

private static StringBuilder prepareStringBuilder() {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    buf.append("{\"status\":\"success\",\"id\":\"1\"}");
    buf.append("{\"status\":\"success\",\"id\":\"2\"}");
    buf.append("{\"status\":\"success\",\"id\":\"3\"}");
    buf.append("{\"status\":\"success\",\"id\":\"4\"}");
    buf.append("{\"status\":\"success\",\"id\":\"5\"}");
    buf.append("{\"status\":\"success\",\"id\":\"6\"}");
    return buf;
}
}
```